# Switch between usercontrol in same grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Hy guys please help.
I'm working in WPF program. I have a grid named body_grid where I display my usercontrols in MainWindow.

My problem is that I can not switch between usercontrol in parent grid.

E.g usercontrolA is displayed in body_grid with button.

Now a usercontrolA button must remove usercontrolA in body_grid and display usercontrolB.

How can I do that please help

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented using Visibility property. If you are not using MVVM patern, code below shows a example of what you are trying to accomplish:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    userControlB.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
    userControlA.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;        
}
```

Comment: Can I clear grid from usercontrolA and and usercontrolB as new child.

Comment: Button in usercontrolA MainWindow m = MainWindow(); m.body_grid.Children.Clear(); m.body_grid.Children.Add(new UsercontrolB);